# User-specified attributes of data.table get removed

Tags: r, attributes, data.table, persistent, user-defined

I have a function that returns a `data.table` with various useful user-defined attributes attached. I notice, though, that the attributes disappear when one manipulates the data.table.

```
library(data.table)
my_dt <- data.table(col1 = rnorm(20), col2 = letters[1:20])

# store some user attribute
attr(my_dt, 'title') <- 'This is my data.table'
# now it's there
attributes(my_dt)
# but here it's gone
attributes(my_dt[order(col1)])
```

Is there any way to make attributes of a data.table 'persist' for cases like the above (besides just storing them in a separate object)?

It seems attributes do persist for regular `data.frames`

```
my_df <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(20), col2 = letters[1:20])

# store some user attribute
attr(my_df, 'title') <- 'This is my data.frame'
# there it is
attributes(my_df) 
# still there
attributes(my_df[order(my_df$col1), ])
```

Comment: Not currently supported. Open feature request can be found in [data.table#995](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/995).

Comment: Ah, thanks. Did not find any earlier discussion of this. I'll leave the question here though since you've linked to it from github as evidence of user appetite for this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature has been added to 1.12.0 when subset was made parallel by Matt. So attributes are now being retained.

```r
library(data.table)
my_dt <- data.table(col1 = rnorm(20), col2 = letters[1:20])

attr(my_dt, 'title') <- 'This is my data.table'
attr(my_dt, 'title')
#[1] "This is my data.table"
attr(my_dt[order(col1)], 'title')
#[1] "This is my data.table"
```

Comment: Wow, great to hear and thank you for the (years-later) follow up!